# Co-prime polynomials of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Consider the following finite polynomial $P_0(x)$ where $x$ is an integer:

Then we define $P_1(x)$ as:

$$ P_1(x) = P_0(x) \pm p_k$$

Provided $p_k$ is co-prime to $P_1(x)$ then $P_1(x)$ is co-prime to $P_0(x)$.

### Example

For example, consider $ P_0(x) = x^2 + x+ 1$. Choosing $p_k=-1$

$$ \implies P_0(x) = x^2 +x +1 -1 = x(x+1) $$

Hence, $x+1$ and $x$ are coprime to $x^2 + x+1$ for $x\neq 0$. Similarly, we can also subtract $(x+1)$ and get $P_2(x) = x^2+x+1 - (x+1) = x^2 + 1$. Hence, $x^2 +1$ is coprime to $x^2 + x +1$ as $x$ is coprime to $x^2+x+1$

### Question

Has anyone studied coprime polynomials in depth in the literature? Also, I noticed for $\infty >\deg P(x) >  1$ then $P(x)$ is always coprime to $P'(x) = \frac{dP(x)}{dx}$. Why is this so?

Comment: I don't think your last statement holds; $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2) = 2x$, which is not coprime to $x^2$.

Comment: Ah ... Your, right though I realized something else ... This post will be edited

Comment: As the example by platty illustrates, $P$ and $P'$ are coprime iff $P$ does not have any roots with multiplicity greater than $1$.  [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative#Application_to_finding_repeated_factors).  (Note that $x^2$ has a double root at $0$.)